# JS: Прокрутка внутри блока

Tags: jquery, javascript, прокрутка

Подскажите, есть ли какой-нибудь плагин для JQuery или что-то готовое для этого?

Суть такая:

Есть страница, сначала идёт прокрутка стандартная браузера или колёсиком, потом доходит до определённого блока и прокрутка должна сработать на этот блок. Т.е. пользователь продолжает скроллить, но страница стоит на месте, а внутри этого блока меняются подблоки. Когда эти подблоки закончатся страница должна скроллиться дальше.

Даже не знаю как это спросить у гугла. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: это разве не поведение по умолчанию ?

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/MHLWA/

Comment: нет, во-первых у меня внутренний блок не имеет скролла, как такового.
А, во-вторых, в вашем примере внутренний блок не прокручивается внутри себя, а просто прокручивается вся страница.

Comment: что такое бампнуть?=)

Comment: какой браузер ? в хроме все прокручивается как у вас описано, а то что у вас там нет скролла, и прочего, надо описывать в вопросе.

Comment: бампнуть - поднять тред наверх, тут это происходит путем редактирования.

Comment: если бы я мог сделать как вы написали, я бы не задавал подобных вопросов.
Кстати, предложенный вами метод не работает, если прокручивать за ползунок. Я поэтому сказал, что он не работает. А мне нужно чтобы работало в обоих случаях.
Я может не совсем точно описал, но вроде как теги и слово _меняются_, а не скроллятся блоки, должно было подразумевать, что внутри этого блока скролл должен обрабатываться на js, а не внутренним скролом.

Comment: ну это сложно вот так взять и сделать в целом можно, но вы не справитесь, а форум этот для того чтобы вы смогли написать код а не скопипастили или спросили как искать. Я вообще не думаю что это реализовано хоть раз нормально, т.к. не нужно.

Comment: никогда не слышал такого, обычно, вроде, говорят апнуть.

я то справлюсь, но не надеялся, что смогу избавиться от нудной рутины, если вдруг уже есть что-то похожее. Я где-то встречал такую фигню, но уже не найду.

И не надеялся скопипастить, а вот взять готовый каракас и понять, как это вообще реализовано это да, было бы неплохо.

Форум он для совместного поиска решений, в том числе и готовых.

Comment: > это разве не поведение по умолчанию ?

Пример не работает в Chrome 34.0.1847.116 m. А не работает он, как я осмелюсь предположить, потому что это еще зависит и от драйвера мыши или какого-то верхнего слоя, который как-то зависит от драйвера (доказано в рамках моей машины случайно, в процессе методичных замен манипуляторов и, соответственно, драйверов к ним). Видимо, есть какая-то инструкция, согласно которой решается, кому важнее передать событие скролла: ближайшему элементу, который может быть прокручен, либо текущему активному элементу.

Comment: Прошу прощения, у меня работает, оказалось, что это так расширение Wheel Smooth Scroller повлияло.

Однако, у ТС, по всей видимости, случай экзотический, поэтому тут это вообще не при чем. Если нужно, чтобы, кроме всего работало и при перетаскивании ползунка, то нужен такой хак: в месте блока резервируем пустое место в теле страницы для подблоков, при достижении нужного scrollTop начинаем отлавливать его, и в зависимости от этого, вручную прокручиваем содержимое в блоке.

Сейчас попробую набросать...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот мой пример: http://jsfiddle.net/dnVy5/

Проверено в Chrome 34.0.1847.116 m.

Разумеется, нуждается в обработке напильником.

Comment: Это круто, мужик. Большое спасибо.
Не везде работает, но не суть. Основной посыл я уловил, теперь есть над чем работать.

Comment: На здоровье :)

Вот, пофиксил, теперь работает и в ff, и в ie9: http://jsfiddle.net/dnVy5/3/ (дело было в `document.body.scrollTop`).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dnVy5/6/

Comment: последний вариант уже не работает, а вот версия 3 работает хорошо

Answer (score 0):

Подобные вещи можно делать с помощью [scrollmagic](http://scrollmagic.io/)

Вот пример реализации:

```
var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    duration: 100,    // the scene should last for a scroll distance of 100px
    offset: 1100        // start this scene after scrolling for 1100px
});
scene.setPin(".app-slider") // pins the element for the scene's duration
scene.on("progress", function (event) {
    $('.app-slide').css('top','-'+event.progress*100+'px');
    console.log("Scene progress changed to " + event.progress);
});
scene.addTo(controller) // assign the scene to the controller
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.